# Code Beautifier and Formatter

Tags: javascript, css

I was just wondering how "stackoverflow" beautify submitted code.
I searched the web and also found the way to beautify the code.
But main problem is: When I put description of my problem and code-snippet.
At that point how we Highlight the code-snippet only but not the description of the problem.

I use some of the CSS from the link but did not find the answer.

http://lifehacker.biz/articles/web-developers-package-code-beautifier-and-formatter/

**UPDATED-**
In my problem whole question(description + code-snippet) is present in a column of the database. It comes by a Struts2 tag , So at that point how I distinguish the code-snippet part and the description part to apply the the code beautifier.

Comment: What are you asking in that last sentence??  Are you asking how to format your code snippet when submitting a question in StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how stack overflow does it is: you have to indent the text by 4 spaces.

You could use <code> tag in HTML to specify which part is code and run the plugin only

```
 $('code').beautifier()
```

or beautifier is whatever plugin you are using

Try chilli for example: http://noteslog.com/chili/

Basically use code tags to specify what is code and what's note. Chilli does it pretty easily.

Comment: In my problem whole question(description + code-snippet) is present in a column of the database. It comes in a tag , So at that point how I distinguish the code-snippet part to apply <code> tag ???

Comment: You'll have to store the code part with a <code>tag</code>

Provide the user the option to do that. It is very difficult to differentiate code and description if there is no clear marking .

Especially with languages like Xcode and even with javascript. It can be done, but is very difficult to differentiate text and code in on text without demarkation and I don't think a lot of people have done it

try google code prettify, but I don't think it does what u ask. m not sure